# Not getting intellisense for mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, typescript-typings

Communicating node application with mongodb without mongoose, installed typing for node and mongdb, it now yields typings folder and I have refrence of index.d.ts in server.ts file i'm importing mongodb module like this in server.ts(using VSCode IDE)

> var mongodb = require('mongodb');

when im doing like this to have function like Clientconnect im not getting intellisense for that

> mongodb.

Comment: Would be handy to know which editor/IDE you're using.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `import ... from ...` instead of `var ... require ...`.

Install mongodb and it's typings.

```
$ npm install mongodb @types/mongo
```

And then one of the following import options.

```
import * as db from 'mongodb';
import db = require('mongodb');
```

You should then be able to use VSCode Intellisense for `db`.

```
db.MongoClient.connect(...);
```

It's also possible to import just what you're going to use, like this.

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
MongoClient.connect(...);
```